# Adding table header row disables jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, jquery-selectors

Using jQuery I can highlight a cell when I compare 2 cells in the same row that are not the same.

```
$(".g-rebuild-thumb-list tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("td")[2].innerHTML != $(this).find("td")[3].innerHTML) {
        $(this).find("td")[0].bgColor = "red";
    }
});
```

Here is a JS fiddle that works as expected:
http://jsfiddle.net/HY2Q3/

However, if I add a header to the table it does not work.

```
<tr>
<th>head</th>
<th>head2</th>
<th>head3</th>
<th>head4</th>
```

Full JS fiddle of same code with a header row added:
http://jsfiddle.net/kah2J/

Can somebody suggest a solution or a explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are still basing the selector of the `tr`, which you've also added for your headers. i updated the jsfiddle, and added `tbody` and `thead`, but you don't have to use them. you could simply add a class to the `tr` that you want the selector to be applied to, and swap out the `td` in your jQuery for the class name. here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HY2Q3/2/

Comment: Albert,Thanks for the fiddle and the explanation, works like a charm.